# Calculating large data from database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I created a table (client side) calculating inventory from a database, the database has a huge amount of data importing from local files, but the table (client side) has more then 30 columns, most of the columns is just calculations calculating inventory from the database based on the product, but the rows of the items are just 700 items, and I'm getting a error from the browser 'This webpage is not available', and when I try to retrieve just 400 items its working perfectly, so what is the problem when retrieving and calculating items with 30 columns for 700 items,

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you're running out of memory?  Do you have error logs you can look at?

Comment: @Explosion Pills Yes, I tried to increase the memory with 1000m, it doesn't helped me

Comment: At some point you can run out of memory either at the server or client.  If you try to stuff too much data into a web page, the browser will freeze and so might the computer.  Usually it's just the browser though.  On the server, it's a similar situation but the details are different.  There is only so much RAM available and if the amount of data combined with the way you are persisting it exceeds that amount, then you have a problem.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk So what is the best solution to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is timing out. Use the php function `set_time_limit(0)`. 
By passing the zero, no time limit is imposed.